# What kind of conjugation is 済{す}ませた?

Tags: grammar, learning

This is from the anime Noir, Episode 1 starting at 23:13 at the school:

> [The two characters A and B are leaving the country.]
>   A: 出国{しゅっこく}の手配{てはい}は済{す}ませた。
>   　'I've made the arrangements to leave the country.'
>   B: ありがとう。

My question is about the conjugation of `済ませた`. I would have expected to hear: `済まして(い)た`. I can't figure out what kind of conjugation that is. It looks like the potential form with `iru`, but I've never seen a past potential form. Plus, 'can finished' or 'can have finished' is much different than 'have finished'. So again, what kind of conjugation is `済ませた`? How is it formed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is simply the 〜た form of 済ませる, which basically means the same as 済ます.

Quoted from [大辞泉](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E6%B8%88%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B&dtype=0&dname=0na&stype=0):

> すま・せる【済ませる】
>       「済ます」に同じ。

And [大辞林](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E6%B8%88%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B&dtype=0&dname=0ss&stype=0):

> すま・せる 【済ませる】
>   「すます（済）」に同じ。

Comment: I don't think my Japanese is good enough to actually understand what any of that is saying.

Comment: Those quotes are simply the references that say that 済ませる and 済ます are exactly the same. I think "「済ます」に同じ" should be simple enough for beginner to understand.

Comment: Fair enough. X ni onaji is a simple :)

But all that other stuff is distracting to a beginner. Or someone not familiar enough with Kanji.

Comment: Fine. I've edited the quotes to your liking.

Comment: So after some more digging around, I found out that sumaseru is the causative form of sumu. AND ALSO the potential form of sumasu. Go figure. So it must be the causative form being used in my snippet. Learn something new everyday.

Comment: @dotnetN00b. You are right but 済ませる is also a root verb on its own. It's not uncommon to have a verb that looks the same as conjugated forms of other verbs. Examples: 任せる (root vs potential), 生まれる (root vs passive), 切れる (root v potential) etc.